# Message validation rules

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I wonder if I should divide this class into two, since it contains two "ifs" with different messages. Would breaking it down be in keeping with the "S" of SOLID?

```
internal class ValidDateApuration : IBusineeOfValidation<DtoFormGnre>
{
    public MessageValidation Validar(DtoFormGnre obj)
    {
        var paymentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj.Date);
        var today = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-DateTime.Now.Day + 1);
        var messageValidation = new MessageValidation { isValid = true };

        if ((paymentDate <= new DateTime(2016, 01, 01)))
        {
            messageValidation.isValid = false;
            messageValidation.Mensage = string.Format("Xxx...!");
        }

        if (today > new DateTime(2016, 01, 01))
        {
            var campareResult = DateTime.Compare(today, paymentDate);

            if (campareResult == 0)
            {
                if (today.Month == 2)
                {
                    messageValidation.isValid = false;
                    messageValidation.Mensagem = "YYYYYYY!";
                }
                else
                {
                    messageValidation.isValid = false;
                    messageValidation.Mensagem = string.Format("ZZzzzzzzz!");
                }
            }

            if (campareResult >= 1)
            {
                messageValidation.isValid = true;
                messageValidation.Mensage = "";
            }
        }

        return messageValidation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help us help you, [edit] your post to add a bit of plain-English description of what problem your code is solving.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35185081/1188513)

Comment: Is it just a typo that the `campareResult >= 1` branch is assigning `messageValidation.Mensage` when the other two are assigning `messageValidation.Mensagem`? Giving us your real, actual code from your IDE is always a better idea on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown performs two checks, both of which have to do with dates.

Splitting these up might be a good idea if you want to perform these checks in different combinations, e.g. if you have to implement another usecase where the only requirement is that the paymentDate must be after 2016-01-01.

In my eyes, this would not break the single responsibility principle. As new features are added, what was once a single responsibility might become too broad.

A problem might be that there is no `return messageValidation;`  after the first check. Are you sure these checks are truly independet? Looks to me as if the error message of the second check overrules the one of the first.

Good luck :>